# How to check how much percent of scrollview is visible?

Tags: android, scrollview

I've used following code to get scroll percentage but I'm getting this only after scrolling. How can we get scroll percentage visible without scrolling. For eg. in onCreate() method.

```
  scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                    float scrollPercent = (scrollY + scrollView.getMeasuredHeight()) / (webView.getBottom() * 1f);
}
}
```

Comment: before you scroll, scroll percent is obviously 0

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I mean how much percent of scrollview is visible

Comment: use `android.view.ViewTreeObserver` with `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `scrollView.getScrollY();` without the `OnScrollChangeListener`, using the calculation you already have.